# Divi Wordpress Theme: Top Parent Level Not Clickable & Does not Link to Page on Mobile Menu with Collapse Nested Items

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

Divi automatically presents mobile menu when the media screen width is less than 1025px. By default, all menu items, including sub-menu items, are displayed in full expanded view with all menu items on the list.

Problem is, the parent level menu item no longer linkable to its own web page. In other words, tapping on the parent menu item that has nested sub-menus only expand or collapse the sub-menus, even though the parent menu itself leads to a valid web page URL, essentially preventing visitors to access the web page.

I've already tried [this](https://techjourney.net/top-parent-level-not-clickable-not-link-to-page-on-divi-mobile-menu-with-collapse-nested-items/) fix I found online, but it doesn't work.

#main-header .et_mobile_menu .menu-item-has-children > a:after { font-size: 16px; content: '4c'; top: 13px; right: 10px; }
    #main-header .et_mobile_menu .menu-item-has-children.visible > a:after { content: '4d'; }
    #main-header .et_mobile_menu ul.sub-menu { display: none !important; visibility: hidden !important;  transition: all 1.5s ease-in-out;}
    #main-header .et_mobile_menu .visible > ul.sub-menu { display: block !important; visibility: visible !important; }
    
    
    (function($) {

```
    function setup_collapsible_submenus() {
        var $menu = $('#mobile_menu'),
            top_level_link = '#mobile_menu .menu-item-has-children > a';

        $menu.find('a').each(function() {
            $(this).off('click');

            if ( $(this).is(top_level_link) ) {
                if ($(this).parent().hasClass('always-visitable')) {
                    $('<a class="hover-link"></div>')
                    .attr('href', $(this).attr('href'))
                    .on('click', function(e){ e.stopPropagation(); })
                    .appendTo($(this));
                }

                $(this).attr('href', '#');
            }

            if ( ! $(this).siblings('.sub-menu').length ) {
                $(this).on('click', function(event) {
                    $(this).parents('.mobile_nav').trigger('click');
                });
            } else {
                $(this).on('click', function(event) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    $(this).parent().toggleClass('visible');
                });
            }
        });
    }

    $(window).load(function() {
        setTimeout(function() {
            setup_collapsible_submenus();
        }, 700);
    });

})(jQuery);
</script>

**Also the CSS:**

#main-header .et_mobile_menu .always-visitable {
    position: relative;
}
#main-header .et_mobile_menu .always-visitable .hover-link {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0;
    right: 60px; /* right area continues to expand or collapse */
```

Comment: Did you find a fix yet?

Answer (score 1):

Go to Divi theme options > Navigation > General Settings > Disable top tier dropdown menu links.

Answer (score 0):

In case somebody it's looking for an alternative solution, I've used [this post](https://techjourney.net/top-parent-level-not-clickable-not-link-to-page-on-divi-mobile-menu-with-collapse-nested-items/) as reference to modify the menu behaviour:

It basically adds an extra *<a></a>* element to the top level menu item. The original wrapper *a* element toggles the drop-down and its only triggered when the element is clicked outside the inner *a* element which is absolutely positioned with respect to the wrapper *a* element.

I leave my modified code here. Take care of the classes selectors in your implementation they might be different.

```html
<!-- Make top level menu items clickable and side button to display the dropdown -->
<style type="text/css">
.et_slide_in_menu_container .et_mobile_menu .menu-item-has-children > a { 
    background-color: transparent; 
    position: relative; 
}

.et_slide_in_menu_container .et_mobile_menu .always-visitable {
    position: relative;
}
.et_slide_in_menu_container .et_mobile_menu .always-visitable .hover-link {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; 
    left: 0; 
    bottom: 0;
    right: 60px; /* right area continues to expand or collapse */
    width: calc(100% - 2rem);
    height: 100%;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
(function($) {
      
    function setup_collapsible_submenus() {
        console.log("Menu script loaded!")
        //
        var $menu = $('#mobile_menu_slide'),
            top_level_link = '#mobile_menu_slide .menu-item-has-children > a';
             
        $menu.find('a').each(function() {
            $(this).off('click');
              
            if ( $(this).is(top_level_link) ) {
                if ($(this).parent().hasClass('always-visitable')) {
                    $('<a class="hover-link"></div>')
                    .attr('href', $(this).attr('href'))
                    .on('click', function(e){ e.stopPropagation(); })
                    .prependTo($(this));
                }

                $(this).attr('href', '#');
            }
              
            if ( ! $(this).siblings('.sub-menu').length ) {
                $(this).on('click', function(event) {
                    $(this).parents('.mobile_nav').trigger('click');
                });
            } else {
                $(this).on('click', function(event) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    $(this).parent().toggleClass('visible');
                });
            }
        });
    }
      
    $(window).load(function() {
        setTimeout(function() {
            setup_collapsible_submenus();
        }, 700);
    });
 
})(jQuery);
</script>
```